# Use NodeJS to change what text HTML displays

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

So I creating a site for learning purposes. I want someone to be able to type in there name on the "sign in" page then you'll be sent to the home page where it will display a Welcome (enter name here) h1. I will include my code and pictures of the page. Please help.

Note: Im just trying to manipulate the DOM. Can I do that with JQuery?

[This is what the sign in page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlrXb.jpg)

[Here is the Code for the sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhsHs.jpg)

[Here is the what the Home page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRFoA.jpg)

[Here is the code for the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzIsW.jpg)

[Here is the app.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5RvZ.jpg)

Thanks for your help in advanced.

I am going to put the code in text also.

```
app.js  

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new JSDOM("");
const $ = require("jquery")(window);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signin.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  const fname = req.body.fname;
  console.log(fname);
});

app.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
  console.log("Listening");
});

changeName = function (name) {
  window.document.querySelector("h1").innerText = name;
};

HTML For Home PAGE----------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Aquascaper</title>
    <!-- <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Nav Bar -->

    <div class="bg-img">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="img/logo-long.svg" class="logo no-overlay" />
          <nav class="nav_links">
            <a href="">About</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
            <button class="calc-btn">
              Calculator
            </button>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase-text">
          <h1>Welcome,</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Showcase -->

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>

 HTML FOR SIGN IN PAGE ---------------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SignIn</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signin.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="overlay">
      <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <img
          class="mb-4 logo"
          src="img/logo.svg"
          alt=""
          width="150"
          height="150"
        />
        <h1 class="">Enter Name to Enter Site</h1>
        <input
          name="fname"
          type="text"
          id="inputName"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="First Name"
          required
          autofocus
        />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">
          Sign in
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey i know it might not sound good initially but you should implement it in template engine like handlebars ,ejs instead of raw html and best part is they looks exactly same  as HTML hope this helps

Comment: @harshitkohli Thanks for trying to help. I am new and do not know handlebars.

Comment: that's why i'm suggesting you directly jump on that it's exactly same as HTML in simple words HTML with logic  it'll solve this problem easily backend rendering template with embedded data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate a cliend-side DOM from server-side. However you can use [ejs](https://ejs.co/)

```
npm install ejs
```

and then on your server-side page use

`app.get('/homepage', function(req, res) {
    res.render('homepage.ejs', {username: name});
});`

and on your homepage.ejs use

```
<h1>Welcome, <%= username %></p>
```